# Handle button click inside row in recyclerView

Tags: android, database, onclick, android-recyclerview, adapter

I would like to know how to handle position of the row if the adapter is changed - for example if I write something to SearchView - adapter has changed and position is different. I have done this (below), but it shows the item before changed position.

My issue is with Recycler view item click.

Could you help me with that?

Adapter

```
public class ContactsRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactsRecyclerAdapter.BindingHolder> {

    private static OnItemClickListener listener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View itemView, int position);
    }
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    private List<Contact> mContacts;
    private List<Contact> mContactsFiltered;
    SearchViewFilter filter;
    Context mContext;

    public ContactsRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> contact) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mContacts = contact;
        this.mContactsFiltered = contact;
        filter = new SearchViewFilter(mContacts, this);
    }

    public static class BindingHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ViewDataBinding binding;

        public BindingHolder(final View rowView) {
            super(rowView);
            binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(rowView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null)
                        listener.onItemClick(itemView, getLayoutPosition());
                }
            });
        }
        public ViewDataBinding getBinding() {
            return binding;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public BindingHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int type) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item_contact, parent, false);
        BindingHolder holder = new BindingHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BindingHolder holder, int position) {
        final Contact contact = mContactsFiltered.get(position);
        holder.getBinding().setVariable(BR.contact, contact);
        holder.getBinding().executePendingBindings();
    }
```

Fragment

```
   public class ContactListFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

        FloatingActionButton fabButton;
        SearchView searchView;
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        String name, number, email;

        private List<Contact> mContact = new ArrayList<>();
        private ContactsRecyclerAdapter mAdapter;

        public static ContactListFragment newInstance() {
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            ContactListFragment fragment = new ContactListFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact_list, container, false);

            searchView = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.search_view);

            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
            mContact = SugarRecord.listAll(Contact.class);

            mAdapter = new ContactsRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), mContact);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            //item click
            mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ContactsRecyclerAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View itemView, int position) {
                    Contact contact = SugarRecord.findById(Contact.class, (long) position + 1);

                    name = contact.getName();
                    number = contact.getNumber();
                    email = contact.getEmail();
                    showAlertDialog();
                }
            });

            searchFilter();

            return view;
        }

public void sortList() {
        if(mContact.size() > 0) {
            if (!isSort) {
                Collections.sort(mContact, new Comparator<Contact>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Contact contact1, Contact contact2) {
                        return contact1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(contact2.getName());
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                Collections.reverse(mContact);
                isSort = false;
            }
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click listener does not work with a RecyclerView. use OnItemTouchListener()

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
      @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        // do whatever
      }

      @Override public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
        // do whatever
      }
   })
);
```

Comment: Thats the same I have. But my point is how to check if the position is different. For example I have some name- 1. Tom, 2. Adele, 3. Beta , then I sort them A - Z (so they are "mixed"). So the first is Adele, then Beta and Tom. But If I click on 2. item, it shows me Adele (so position is the same), but i want to show Beta.

Comment: you are getting position passed inside the method, use that position to get the value from the List that your adapter is working on. i.r yourList.get(position) will get you the item for that position

Comment: since the list will be sorted, position 2 will be occupied by Beta and you will get that at yourList.get(position)

Comment: Ok, but i forgot to say that i get data from database, so the database position?

Comment: Save the data which you got in a list and sort that as well. Then use the position. It will virtually be the same as getting the position from database

Comment: The problem is that I sort the list, but the core data in database are in the same position.

Comment: @Stepan your should use the `id` of the item in the DB, instead of mapping index of array to the row of the DB. The way you're doing will cause a lot of pain and suffering in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you have to overide onclick in BindingHolder class. Inside onclick method  invoke a callback method of object passed via constructor etc

```
public static class BindingHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ViewDataBinding binding;

    public BindingHolder(final View rowView) {
        super(rowView);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(rowView);

        public void onClick(View view) {
        //call a callback method here
        }
    }
    public ViewDataBinding getBinding() {
        return binding;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be please more specific? I am quite a beginner.